# Cannot Access RDP

Tags: powershell, rdp

I'm trying to run the following commands con a Windows11 VM

```
netsh advfirewall firewall set rule group="remote" new enable=Yes

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Remote" dir=in protocol=TCP localport=3389 action=allow

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Remote" dir=out protocol=TCP localport=3389 action=allow

net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add

net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" ANOTHER_GUEST /add

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\Userlist" /v ANOTHER_GUEST /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server'-name "fDenyTSConnections" -Value 0

Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Remote Desktop*" | Select DisplayName, Enabled

Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName "Remote Desktop*" | Set-NetFirewallRule -enabled true

Enable-NetFirewallRule -DisplayGroup "Remote Desktop*"

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp' -name "UserAuthentication" -Value 1

New-Item -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" -Force | Out-Null

New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp" -Name "UserAuthentication" -Value "00000000" -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

However I'm still not being able to access through RDP, Windows keeps saying that the remote server is not active or remote is turned off or not available on the network

What am I doing wrong here?

I was expecting to be able to add rules to the firewall and enable RDP by doing this

Comment: You can only access folder if you have an account on local and remote machine.  Can you access folder using a file explorer?  Are you an admin?  If you are going to a remote machine you need two backslashes at beginning of path : "\\HKLM:\SYSTEM\......" if you are an admin use dollar sign instead of colon : "\\HKLM$\SYSTEM\.....".  You do not need credentials.  Credentials are block on windows machine.  Try with file explorer using two backslashes and see if you have access.  Get file explorer to work before trying in code.

Comment: It didn't help me. I have done this before but for some reason this is not working and I keep having the same error message and I even tried this on different PCs

Comment: Did you check event viewer on local and remote machines?  Are you in a corporate network?  Do you have admin rights on entire network.  This may be a Group Policy Issue.  The machines may not be in your domain.  You can try ping (try IP and Machine Name) the machines to see if there is a route.  A router may be down.

Comment: I'm in a private network and the account I'm using has admin rights. I haven't checked event viewer however but what I don't understand is why in the same conditions before I managed to acces through rdp and not being able now. I have also  Test-NetConnection -ComputerName "computername" -CommonTCPPort "RDP" -InformationLevel "Detailed" and sometimes I'm able to ping and sometime dont however successfully ping or not the tcp connection on 3389 fails. I don't uderstand what I may be doing differently to the previous successful attempts

Comment: Maybe looking at the event files will give you the answer.  Do you want me to guess an answer?  if ping fails you may have hardware issues.  I usually check ping with large amount of data to see if there are errors : ping -t -l  65500 IP which pings continuously with packets that are 65500 in length.

Comment: I will try that and also will try to reinstall the VM to see if it works